# How to properly setup modules for Google App Engine (PHP runtime)

Tags: google-app-engine, configuration, module, google-app-engine-php

I want to create very standard setup for GAE (php runtime): 2 modules with specific URLs (*routings*):

- **module-api** for REST API
- **module-oli** for backend static process ..

regarding to doc (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/ and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/routing) I've created 3 .yaml config files:

**dispatch.yaml**

```
application: ABC

dispatch:
- url: "*/oli/*"
  module: module-oli

- url: "*/"
  module: module-api
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: ABC
version: v1
module: module-api
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: public/api.php
```

**module-oli.yaml**

```
application: ABC
version: v1
module: module-oli
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: public/oli.php
```

I also tried many changes in URL handling, but the error I always get is "**Duplicate module: module-api**".

Can you help me please? Thank you in advance ..

Comment: Normally app.yaml would be for your default module. You might need to redeploy your default module and then deploy your two modules separately. That's what I would do!

Comment: thank you @Tom, even if do not specify module in app.yaml (leaving it as default) and in dispatch.yaml pointing default calls ("*/") to module: default .. it still says "duplicate module: default" ..

I'm very lost with it, because I do not see anything wrong there .. thank you ..

Comment: You should also remove the "application" line form your dispatch.yaml

Comment: You should remove the "application" line from your dispatch.yaml then deploy using  `appcfg.py -A <PROJECT_ID> update_dispatch .`

Comment: it still says the same :( .. thank you :) ..

Comment: I have just set this up and got it to work on a project of mine. I made some minor tweaks to the dispatch file

Comment: ```dispatch:

  - url: "*/oli/*"
    module: module-oli

  - url: "*/api/*"
    module: module-api
```

Comment: Or you could remove the second dispatch rule and leave it to your default module.

Comment: Which command actually gives you the error?

Comment: thank you for helping me .. it looks like I'm really doing something wrong ..


on a local machine I'm starting the project via GoogleAppEngineLauncher, and (as is written in doc) I've putted extra flags specifying dispatch.yaml, app.yaml, module-oli.yaml .. GoogleAppEngineLauncher says "duplicate module" ..


if I update (even dispatch) the deploy version at gcloud, it looks like gcloud does not see the 2nd module ..


sorry for taking your time @tom, there are not so many documentation.


thank you so much for help ..

Comment: I do not think you can use dispatch.yaml in that way

Comment: Try without specifying dispatch.yaml

Comment: finally found the solution, will check out how it works with dispatch (should be according to this article https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/routing) and post the solution .. thank you @Tom for help ..

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but (*on my computer*) it does not work just from googleAppEngineLauncher.app (*OSX 10.11.3, googleAppEngineLauncher version 1.9.32*), but it works if I use command line tools:

dev_appserver.py app.yaml module-oli.yaml

and only if I do not use param --skip_sdk_update_check (does not matter value)

more **about naming modules** (*and using default module or not*) .. it all works even if I name default module with specific name (*of course, it causes error when not all request are dispatched to the module*).

more **about dispatching to modules**; it works (*as it's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/routing)*). of course, it does not work at local development environment, as every single module runs at a different port (*than the dispatch does not work, and if there is a module with manual_scaling, the _ah/start can not be handled and as err500 it stops the start*)

here are all setup files, and how to run it:

app.yaml

```
application: <APPLICATION-ID>
module: default
version: v1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: blablabla.php
```

module-oli.yaml

```
application: <APPLICATION-ID>
version: v1
module: module-oli
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

instance_class: B1

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
  - url: /oli/.*
    script: blebleble-oli.php
```

dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/oli/*"
    module: module-oli

  - url: "*/*"
    module: default
```

to run on local development environment: **dev_appserver.py app.yaml module-oli.yaml** .. (*no automatic routing, instances are running on different ports*)

one everything is deployed to gcloud and dispatching is updated (appcfg.py -A wellfedcat-1221 update_dispatch .), it works like this:

- **APPLICATION-ID.appspot.com/*** : served by default module ..
- **APPLICATION-ID.appspot.com/oli/*** : served by module-oli ..

the dispatching is necessary when you want to use our own domain to map to gcloud ..

thank you @Tom for help!